# Movie where the main character wakes up with amnesia in a post-apocalyptic world run by three superhuman generals

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

The movie takes place in a future destroyed by war. Not much is shared with the viewer about how or what caused this war. We see the main character waking up to this world with no memory of anything prior to his awakening. He is quickly thrust into the setting and finds himself at the heart of this war.

Three superhumans run all of humanity as generals of the army which is all that remains of humanity. These generals are marching their army to a doomsday weapon that is going to destroy the planet. Our hero discovers he is one of the genetic humans created to lead the world's remaining humans, like the three generals are now. He had found out about their plans with the doomsday device and tried to stop them. Having been defeated and left for dead the three thought nothing would stand in their way.

The doomsday device will in fact kill everything. The generals had become tired of life with nothing but blood shed. They wanted it all to end. Our hero does stop it but the ending is still sad as we see nothing really remains but him and the love interest in the story.

The film is Asian with English subtitles. It is late 2000s sci-fi with live-action anime-style fight scenes. The setting is very diesel punk and has some unique cinematography. It uses a sepia tone and a lot of close-ups of the cogs and gears of the world around them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is ***[Casshern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshern_(film))*** (2004).

> *Casshern* (キャシャーン, Kyashān) is a 2004 Japanese *tokusatsu* superhero film adaptation of the anime series of the same name. It was written and directed by Kazuaki Kiriya. It is one of only a few films (*Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow*, *Immortal* (both 2004) and *Sin City* (2005), among others) to be shot entirely on a "digital backlot".

After a long war, the Eastern Federation, led by a human general, has triumphed over Europa and taken control of the Eurasian continent. However, many citizens of the Eastern Federation are sick and dying as a result of pollution.

A scientist, Dr. Azuma, has discovered a special type of cell, dubbed the 'Neo Cell,' which he believes can be used to culture replacement body parts for the sick. He's offered funding and laboratory to work in within a military building.

Against his father's wishes, Azuma's son, Tetsuya, joins the army to fight 'terrorists,' leaving behind his  fiancée, Luna. He's subsequently killed in action by a grenade. A casket containing Tetsuya's body is brought to the building his father works at.

On the same day, the building is struck by lightning, which stimulates a pool of Neo Cells inside the building, causing various body parts floating within it to knit themselves together, creating a race of superhumans, dubbed 'Neo Sapiens.'

The army panics and sends in soldiers to ruthlessly gun the Neo Sapiens down. The Neo Sapiens attempt to flee, but most of them are killed.

While this is going on, Azuma brings Tetsuya's body to the pool of Neo Cells, which resurrects him. However, he's extremely weak, and is driven off to safety by Luna and her father, Kozuki, a scientist specialising in the development of armour.

Four of the Neo Sapiens -- three men and a woman -- also manage to escape, and make their way to a mountainous region, where they find a deserted fortress housing a dormant army of robots. One of the Neo Sapiens, Burai, becomes the de facto leader.

The Neo Sapiens are enraged by the slaughter of their brethren, and decide to use the robot army to wage war on humanity. They also kidnap human scientists to force them to work in robot factories.

They attempt to kidnap Kozuki, but their attack on his laboratory awakens Tetsuya from a liquid-filled chamber he was sleeping in. Tetsuya is now clad in high-tech combat armour, and manages to kill the female Neo Sapien, but is defeated by Burai.

In the climax...

> ... the Eastern Federation launches a full-scale assault on Burai's fortress. Burai responds by activating a giant robot that contains a nuclear bomb set to detonate on a timer. Tetsuya tries to prevent the detonation but fails, and he and Luna are the only survivors.

Comment: Casshern / That is the one!Thank you so much!